# Conditional Vanilla CSS in React JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, conditional-statements, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build a project using vanilla CSS and React Js and I need help writing a "conditional" css.

In a previous project I wrote a conditional css using tailwind:

```
<p>
        className={`text-cyan-600 font-medium text-sm ${
          post.description.length > 300 ? "text-red-600" : ""
        }`}
      >
        {post.description.length}/300
      </p>
```

This code will turn a text red if it exceeds 300 words.
I'd like to do the same using vanilla CSS but I'm not finding a way to properly write in line styles.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: same should work in vanilla, you're just adding or not a class. define the class in vanilla.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you asking how to put logic in CSS? It's not a programming language. Also, no need for "vanilla". It's just CSS.

Comment: @dandavis , thanks for commenting. I'm trying to use the conditional vanilla css in a few spot in my project. 
Here is one example:

 className={`category-text ${(post.category = "lifestyle"
              ? "turn-blue"
              : " ")}`}
I want to see if post.category is = to a specific key word, and if so to use the "turn-blur" css class, but instead, I get "turn-blue" as a text on my website. I tried a few things but I can't get the logic right.

Comment: @isherwood, 3 other ppl understood my question. If you're the account who voted my question down can you remove it?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add an active state to the text and when the user exceeded 300 w add that class `text.active{color:red;}`

```
(Text.length > 300 && Text.classList.add("active"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Tailwind is just a collection of classes, if you want to go from using tailwind to your own stylesheets, just define your own classes.

styles/globals.css

```css
.text-red {
  color: red;
}
```

Then import the stylesheet where it is needed - at the root component if you want it to be applied globally.

```
import "../styles/globals.scss";

export default function App() {
  const post = { description: new Array(301) };
  return (
    <p className={`${post.description.length > 300 ? 'text-red' : ''}`}>
      {post.description.length}/300
    </p>
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-nuerpf?file=App.tsx,style.css

---

If you want to use inline styling rather than stylesheets, use the `style` property

```
export default function App() {
  const post = { description: new Array(301) };
  return (
    <p style={{ color: post.description.length > 300 ? 'red' : 'inherit' }}>
      {post.description.length}/300
    </p>
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-rcktyk?file=App.tsx

Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style